# Wordpress shortcode for date in 4 days

Tags: wordpress, timestamp, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to make a shortcode that displays the day in four days.

So far, I have this:

```
add_shortcode( 'datein4days', 'mythankyoupage' );
function mythankyoupage() {
    $date = date_i18n( 'j. F' );
    ob_start();
    echo $date;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$date = date_i18n( 'j. F' . **"+4 day"** );
```

But this does obviously not work.

It's important to me that it writes out my date in my local month-names.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wordpress `date_i18n` function's second parameter is the time you wish to display in the format given in the first parameter. This needs to be in UnixTime, an integer representing number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970. You can use the PHP function `strtotime` to get this number, passing in the `"+4 days"` as the parameter.

```
$date = date_i18n('j. F', strtotime("+4 days"));
```